# Get Google Visualization Table responsive on mobile devices

Tags: mobile, html-table, visualization

I would like to get a Google Visualization table responsive on mobile devices.

At the moment there is just a tbody and only `<tr>`.
Is there any parameter that can add a thead and `<th>` into the code?

For example there are these parameters:

```
gvisAreaChart(perfChart,
              options=list(
                width = 1000,
                height=400,
                backgroundColor=backgroundColour
                )
              )
```

Is there one to get the thead and `<th>` in it?
Or another solution to get the headline of the Google Visualization Table separated from the rest of the table to make it responsive?